# Strange stack trace in crash on thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-reports

I am getting a very strange and very occasional, random crash on a secondary thread. I don't know what to make of the stack trace. Any ideas as to what could be happening here would be appreciated please?

[image]

This occurs when drawing strings and images to a graphic context on a background thread.

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: Lacking more evidence -- like an actual crash log or real backtrace from a debugger -- this is only conjecture:  the symptoms described would generally indicate updating the UI from other than the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it - this was caused by calling some of NSString's drawing methods to a graphic context on a secondary thread. They are supposed to be thread safe but it is an iOS6 bug. Can be solved by using Core Text or NSAttributedString drawing methods.